# Select a specific Overload in CheckboxRenderer.DrawCheckBox

Tags: vb.net, renderer

In using the CheckBoxRenderer, ComboboxRenderer, TextBoxRederer, and ButtonReder, how do you set the ForeColor(for Text Color)  and BackColor (for the Rectangle Box).

```
'For CheckBoxRender
Dim gl As Point = GC1.Location
Dim r As Rectangle = GC1.ClientRect
Dim textrect As New Rectangle(r.Left + 1, r.Top, r.Width - 2, r.Height)
Dim s As String = GetCellString(GC1, FMT(GC1.FMTCode))
Dim fnt As Font = GetFont(GC1.Font, DefaultLabelFont)
Dim flags As TextFormatFlags = GC1.TextFormatFlag
Dim i As Image
Dim imagerect As New Rectangle(r.Left + 1, r.Top, r.Width - 2, r.Height)
Dim state As CheckBoxState = GetCheckBoxState(GC1.Enabled, GC1.CheckCellChecked, Focused)

    CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(g, gl, textrect, s, fnt, flags, i, imagerect, Focused)

'For TextBoxRederer
            
Dim s As String = GC1.Value.ToString
Dim fnt As Font = GC1.Font
Dim r As Rectangle = GC1.ClientRect
Dim fc As Color = GC1.ForeColor
Dim bc As Color = GC1.BackColor
Dim r2 As New Rectangle(r.Left + 1, r.Top + 1, r.Width - 2, r.Height - 2)
Dim flags As TextFormatFlags = GC1.TextFormatFlag
Dim state As TextBoxState = GetTextBoxState(GC1.Enabled, Focused)
TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(g, r, s, fnt, r2, flags, state)
```

Comment: Those renderers use VisualStyles to render background and text, hence the current Theme determines the colors ([GetThemeColor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-getthemecolor)), based on the specified state

Comment: [SystemColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemcolors?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Thanks, that explains why no option are avaiable for colors.